# How do I automatically clock-in for SCHEDULED items with org-capture?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture, org-clock

I would like to setup my org-capture template for meetings so that I get automatically clocked into the meeting header on the day and time of the meeting.  So given:

```
* Meeting with client
  SCHEDULED: <2020-05-01 Fri 09:00-09:30>
```

I would like to be clocked into that issue on Friday morning at 9am.

Comment: A bit off topic, but you may want to look at the intent of 'schedule' in org: https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html. "Scheduling an item in Org mode should not be understood in the same way that we understand scheduling a meeting..."

Comment: Thanks for the link!  That note is interesting...  In the example they use an (admittedly humourous) example for the SCHEDULED keyword as a reminder to call someone.  The note then continues after the part you quoted: "In Org mode, scheduling means setting a date when you want to start working on an action item."  I'm finding it a little hard to understand why a meeting isn't pretty much exactly a combination of a "reminder" and "something to work on".  I clock my meetings and I also make notes under my meeting headers, I assumed most people did this.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10506/780 for more discussion. It probably does not matter for your workflow, but you could be using a plain timestamp (`C-c .`), which is what org recommends for meetings/appointments that occur at a specific time and then are over. Scheduling is more about when tasks should start showing up, and has different semantics if you don't complete the task when you planned to.

Comment: After reading your answer there I think it finally clicked.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have these meetings reflected in your clock data afterwards for reporting purposes, I don't think you need to actually clock in and out? You can just add the clock data directly:

```
CLOCK: [2020-05-01 Fri 09:00]--[2020-05-01 Fri 09:30] => 0:30
```

You could come up with a capture template to let you enter the start/end times and put them in both the timestamp and the clock record. Another approach might be a function to scan an org file for meetings and add the clock info, i.e. something you run at the time you want to review the clock data.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought there might be a setting I was missing in `org-capture`.  To be honest, I thought `:clock-in t` would do that, instead of what it does.

Comment: No, the clock commands are really geared towards interactive time tracking. I don't believe Emacs (or Org) has any built-in mechanism for triggering actions on a particular date, actually. Emacs has timers which are more for repeating or near-term things (run this command every 30 minutes, or in 2 hours).